# Python ZMQ examples over WLAN network

Tags: python, tcp, zeromq, pyzmq

For a project I need to communicate between C++ and Python via ZMQ over the WLAN network.
If I use my C++ implementation, everything works fine. I just type in the IP+Port number at the client.bind("tcp:// ...) and I can send messages via WLAN.
If I try the same with the Python Code, it does not work.

So I just tested the python examples (so no C++ anymore): http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:durapub
http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:durasub

I replaced the >localhost< in the client with the IP of my host computer. I do not receive any messages. I am using exactly the code from the example, except the replacement.

Here is the Code:

PUBLISHER:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()

# Subscriber tells us when it's ready here
sync = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
sync.bind("tcp://*:5564")

# We send updates via this socket
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind("tcp://*:5565")

# Wait for synchronization request
sync_request = sync.recv()

# Now broadcast exactly 10 updates with pause
for n in xrange(10):
    msg = "Update %d" % n
    publisher.send(msg)
    time.sleep(1)

publisher.send("END")
time.sleep(1)  # Give 0MQ/2.0.x time to flush output
```

SUBSCRIBER

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()

# Connect our subscriber socket
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, "Hello")
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
subscriber.connect("tcp://192.168.2.119:5565")

# Syncronize with the publisher
sync = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sync.connect("tcp://192.168.2.119:5564")
sync.send("")

# Get updates, expect random Ctrl-C death
while True:
    data = subscriber.recv()
    print data
    if data == "END":
        break
```

Its exactly the example code, except that I changed localhost to the IP Adress of my publisher in the Subscriber-Code. Btw, I did the same in the C++ example Code and it works.

Comment: Check this post: [Communicate between C++ and Python using ZeroMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548582/mql5-zmq-pub-socket-not-being-received-by-python-zmq-sub-socket/53549024#53549024)

Comment: Thanks. But I guess the pyZMQ examples should also work with an IP instead of localhost, shouldn't they? So thats not a C++ to Py problem, there is a diffrent behavior between the C++ durapub.cpp/durasub.cpp and the Python durapub.py/durasub.py

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this field. What do you mean with containers? I edited my post, now you can see what I changed exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake another question with your question! But the container is an instance from an image in Docker that is irrelevant with your question.

Comment: If first of your problem is in Python to Python communication over ZMQ, I will post an answer.

Comment: I tried your example just now, It works well. Does these codes on a machine? If yes you could use `tcp://127.0.0.1` in SUBSCRIBER code instead of self IP. But if SUBSCRIVER and PUBLISHER are in multiple machines, I think your problem is firewall in the port binding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using two Pi´s on the same WLAN Network to communicate. If I am using PUB and SUB on two Processes on the same Pi, it works fine. I do not think its a problem with the firewall, since the C++ example runs well. I am open for any ideas!

Comment: Is not any problem when you are using with two RPi in C++ with the mentioned port? If yes, so your problem is not with the firewall.

Comment: Did you try with `tcp://*:xxxx` method in binding IP+Port?

Comment: It works now. I wrote in the IP of the publisher his own IP instead of *:xxxx. Could you tell me what means * ? By the way, thank you much for your help!

Comment: It is strange. `*` and `0.0.0.0` means all available and accessable IP. could you try with `0.0.0.0:xxxx`?

Comment: I glad that eventually your problem resolved.